# Obstructed JavaScript code: part of codes are not executed starting from second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to trigger a Bootstrap modal (with an Id `testModal`) by a button click and update its content dynamically. Be more precise, I want to check if a certain div tag has been created, if yes then remove it and create a new one. For this I came up with the following jQuery code for testing purpose:

```
jQuery('#testModalButton').on('click', 
  function(){
    'use strict';
    jQuery('#testModalTitle').html('Country list');
    console.log('Check if a div exists');
    //...other codes...//
    var $testModalBodyDiv = null;
    if (jQuery('#testModalBodyDiv').length != 0) {
      // if yes, then remove it.  
      jQuery('#testModalBodyDiv').remove();

    }
    else {
      $testModalBodyDiv
      = jQuery("#testModalBody")
        .append($('<div id="testModalBodyDiv">'));
    }
    // end of...other codes...//
    jQuery('#testModal').modal('show');
  }
);
```

What bugs me is that, after the first click, everything runs fine, `[...other codes...]` is executed and modal is opened too. However, when I click the button again, the modal can be opened, yet the `[...other codes...]` part is not executed at all. At the third click, it runs fine again. This pattern repeats. I am wondering what went wrong.

NOTE ADDED: Well, my stupidity comes from a misuse of

```
$testModalBodyDiv = jQuery("#testModalBody").append($('<div id="testModalBodyDiv">'));
```

which, as a matter of fact, first selected the `testModalBody` instead of `testModalBodyDiv` in my previous codes.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to say without seeing what the "other codes" is.

Comment: Does every click prints 'Check if a div exists'? If it doesn't then perhaps the DOM is not ready. Or the brower is busy with other stuff? Put more log around the [...other codes]... to see what its doing.

Comment: @Minh Kieu:P Yes it does print that every time. However, the `[...other codes...]` are not executed at the 2nd, 4th, 6th...clicks. Weird.

Comment: Of course it is executed, it just doesn't do what you expect. When you hide the modal, it doesn't remove its contents, so the div is removed every other time and added every other time.

Comment: @JJJ: Thanks. What change in the logic is needed?

Comment: I don't see why you need to remove the div, can't you just leave that part out?

Comment: @JJJ: let's say if I have to remove that div every time.

Comment: Then remove it every time? I can't really help without knowing what the code should do.

Comment: Note that you don't need to test if elements exist before using jQuery methods on them. `jQuery('#testModalBodyDiv').remove()` just doesn't do anything if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: @Xavir - as you can see first click remove() the div (if) and the 2nd client recreate the div? If you inspect the DOM, you will see the changes in every click.